# error when trying to create azure functions - consumption plan with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm following the official sample:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.51.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration options
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-cptest-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "functionsapptestsa"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "FunctionApp"

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "test-azure-functions"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#example-usage-in-a-consumption-plan

when I run terraform validate, it passes, but when I'm trying to apply it says:

An argument named "storage_account_access_key" is not expected here.

and

An argument named "storage_account_name" is not expected here.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **upgrade your azure provider**. The support for `storage_account_name` and `storage_account_access_key` [was added in version 2.7](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v2.7.0).

Current version is 2.51.

You can try upgrading using:

```
terraform init -upgrade
```

Without `-upgrade` TF will not [upgrade](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/init.html#child-module-installation) existing modules:

> Re-running init with modules already installed will install the sources for any modules that were added to configuration since the last init, but will **not change any already-installed modules**.

Comment: thank you but that didn't work too. I do believe it's something they broke in this release

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same code, it worked for me with

```
Terraform v0.14.7
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.51.0
```

[image]

You may consider upgrading your terraform version. See [Download Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html).